# 400 (Bad Request) cdn syndication twimg

Tags: wordpress, twitter

My wordpress site dose not fully load and I am getting this error.

```
GET http://dev.saudi-nm.com/cdn-cgi/pe/bag2?r[]=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.syndication.twimg.com%2Fwidgets%2Ftimelines%2Fpaged%2F657829541554057216%3Fcallback%3D__twttr.callbacks.tl_i0_657829541554057216_new%26dnt%3Dfalse%26domain%3Ddev.saudi-nm.com%26lang%3Den%26min_position%3D976039655601770496%26suppress_response_codes%3Dtrue%26t%3D1691161%26tz%3DGMT%252B0300 400 (Bad Request)
```

Please help

Comment: It seems like it is the request issue. are you sending the data using ajax or what you are doing. Please elaborate your question

Comment: I am using Twitter Widget on my site, Whenever I remove it the site will fully loads up.

Comment: share the widget settings

Comment: I embedded twitter from here https://publish.twitter.com/ , using the following sittings.
https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HdNttba.jpg
<code><a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/nm_care?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" data-width="400" data-height="450" data-theme="dark">Tweets by nm_care</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script></code>
However I am still getting the error.
https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HdNtQlF.jpg

Comment: Find the http in your database and the source code and let us know the results

Comment: The widget is not installed on my server, I am just using the embed code from twitter in the HTML widget. Can you kindly be more clear about what should I be looking for in my DB.

Comment: @NasserAlMutairi I believe these errors just mean that the tweet has been deleted. If you copy the post id string from your request into a twitter URL  (twitter.com/<username>/<postid>) , you will likely see the tweet no longer exists.